# css class override of bootstrap-maven class

Tags: css, maven, twitter-bootstrap

I am familiar with how to override a bootstrap css class and I have successfully done so to change the background color of a fixed navbar.  However, I recently made the bootstrap.css and  bootstrap-responsive.css files maven dependencies in my project, thus removing those files from my source code.  Now the override for the navbar-inner is not present and the navbar has returned to the default color.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You can override any css with `selector { property: attribute !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can just override the styles in your custom stylesheet.
Be sure to call your stylesheet after bootstrap.css and bootstrap-responsive.css

Comment: I did verify that my custom css was below the bootstrap links on my page and when I had the bootstrap css files in my project source, the override worked fine.

It was when I removed those files and went with the maven dependency "bootstrap-maven" (see https://github.com/efsavage/Bootstrap-Maven), that the override became invalid.  As you can see on the bootstrap-maven doc page, I had to change my css link path to /ext/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css so that these files can "mount themselves"...  
I still get the default style but even though I still have custom css below, it no longer overrides